# Datatable change a row color with rowcallback

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using datatables and currently stuck in changing a row to another color if a STATEMENT meet the requirement, already tried many things but it has really weird error, my codes are :

```
"rowCallback": function( row, data, index ) {
        if ( data[2] < data[4] ) {
          $('td', row).css('background-color', 'pink');
        }
}
```

While in my response file, i wrote this query :

```
$sql = "SELECT itemid,itemname,stock,unit,minimum FROM item WHERE type LIKE 'homecare'";
```

I want to change the row color if the item's stock is LOWER than the minimum value set by the user.

My current datatable test results are :
[image]

Example test result i have run :

- Below 10 and Above Minimum = Unchanged
- 10 and Above = Red << it should be Unchanged, because it is above minimum
- 50 and Above = Unchanged

While the database settings for both row 'minimum' column are the same number (5)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What exactly is your problem? does `$('td', row).css('background-color', 'pink')` not change the row color? It should.

Comment: @davidkonrad my problem is, the condition should be running if Stock < Minimum. Meanwhile the result in the screenshot shows that 10 < 5 is also changed. I have set the minimum value = 5 for both row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have `9 cc`, `10 cc` and so as values in the `stock` column? If you want numerical comparison you must extract the number for each column *as* number. I would also add a `.pink` class to the `<tr>`, instead of setting `background-color` on all `<td>`'s.

```
"rowCallback": function( row, data, index ) {
  var stock = parseFloat(data[0]), //data[2]
      minimum = parseFloat(data[1]), //data[4]
      $node = this.api().row(row).nodes().to$();

  if (stock < minimum ) {
     $node.addClass('pink')
  } 
}
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/104o96cn/**

Comment: The row parameter is already the tr element. No need to do `this.api().row(row).nodes().to$()`. Just do `$(row).addClass('pink')`.
A multiline var declaration like that is also bad for source control, as adding another variable will require you to replace the semicolon with the comma, thus marking the line as changed.

Comment: @ProblemsLoop 1. You are utterly wrong, you need to go trough the API (you will soon discover changes not are persistent) 2. "source control" may be important for you, but really does not have anything at _all_ to do with the question nor the answer

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about, because the docs don't state that you need to go through the API in a roundabout way. https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback. Even the docs gives an example where they're applying the class to the row itself after turning it into a jquery object (other than the fact that they only did it to a specific cell instead of whole row). "changes are not persistent"? rowCallback is called for all rows "for each table draw". Even the other answers don't go through that roundabout way. Give an example where `$(row).addClass('pink')` fails.

Comment: My comment about your var declaration is a mere comment, which could give a heads up to others who actually use source control. I only combined it with my first comment because I didn't want to put 2 comments. Sorry if that offended you.

Answer (score 4):

New Datatable has the following feature for highlighting the row:

```
"rowCallback": function( row, data, index ) {
        if ( data[2] < data[4] ) {
          //Highlight the cell value
          $(row).find('td:eq(2)').css('color', 'red');
          //Highlight the row
          $(row).addClass("danger");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is how managed to change my data table row background (DataTables 1.10.19)**

```
"fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
        switch(aData['country_id']){
            case 1:
                $('td', nRow).css('background-color', '#dacfcf')
                break;
        }
    }
```